# Determine what is in a user's view in a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, observable

Here is the information you need to know :

This is for a WPF app I am writing for a music app. I have this class called Song (n.b. i'm using Protobuff.net for serialization and ATL.Track from z440.atl.core) :

```
[ProtoContract]
    public class Song : IEquatable<Song>, IComparable<Song>
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        private string mFilePath;

        private BitmapImage mArtwork;

        public BitmapImage Artwork
        {
            get => mArtwork;
            set => mArtwork = value;
        }

        public Song(Track track)
        {
            Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(track.Title) ? string.Empty : track.Title;
            ArtistName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(track.Artist) ? string.Empty : track.Artist;
            AlbumTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(track.Album) ? string.Empty : track.Album;
            AlbumArtist = string.IsNullOrEmpty(track.AlbumArtist) ? string.Empty : track.AlbumArtist;
            Composer = string.IsNullOrEmpty(track.Composer) ? string.Empty : track.Composer;
            Genre = string.IsNullOrEmpty(track.Genre) ? string.Empty : track.Genre;
            Year = track.Year == 0 ? null : (int?)track.Year;
            TrackNumber = track.TrackNumber == 0 ? null : (int?)track.TrackNumber;
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(track.DurationMs);
            DiscNumber = track.DiscNumber == 0 ? null : (int?)track.DiscNumber;
            FilePath = track.Path;
            Comments = string.Empty;
            //This is very costly !
            Artwork = BitmapHelper.LoadImage(track.EmbeddedPictures.FirstOrDefault()?.PictureData);
        }

        public Song()
        {
        }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(5)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(7)]
        public string AlbumArtist { get; set; }
        public Album Album { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(9)]
        public string Composer { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(10)]
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(11)]
        public int? Year { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(12)]
        public int? TrackNumber { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(13)]
        public int? DiscNumber { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(14)]
        public int? PlayCount { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(15)]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(17)]
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
        public string DisplayDuration => Duration.Days != 0 ? Duration.ToString("dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss") : Duration.ToString(Duration.Hours != 0 ? "hh\\:mm\\:ss" : "mm\\:ss");

        public string FilePath
        {
            get => string.IsNullOrEmpty(mFilePath) ? string.Empty : mFilePath;
            set => mFilePath = value;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Song other)
        {
            return string.Compare(FilePath, other?.FilePath, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => FilePath?.GetHashCode() ?? base.GetHashCode();

        public bool Equals([AllowNull] Song other) => other?.FilePath == FilePath;
    }
```

I my viewModel, I have an `ObservableCollection<Song>` called SongList, which is bound to a ListView in my View :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SongList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSong}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        </ListView>
```

The SongList might be too large at any given point to display every Song in the Collection. Is there a way for me to tell which songs in this ListView are currently being shown to the user ?

Comment: Would you be more specific? I will make you a sample.

Comment: I have provided more detail. I hope this is okay.

Comment: This is the same question [you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67215645/how-can-i-determine-whats-in-a-users-view), and which was closed due to lack of clarity. It's a violation of Stack Overflow rules to delete and repost a question to bypass the closure; you are required to [edit the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67215645/edit) to improve it, and wait for the community to agree it should be reopened.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not aware of this. I deleted the question precisely because I thought I needed to reword it completely. I think this is a slightly different question anyway, the last one had too much useless information.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do as simplified as possible? Please continue to try. I will keep an eye on your questions.

Comment: You can't tell which items are currently shown in the view in the view model if that's what you ask. The view model doesn't care about this. So where and why do you need this information?

Comment: With a listbox or listview they virtualise. If you bind your data and template into ui then whatever is templated is in view. Whatever is not templated is not in view. Use a converter to build your picture. Bind using that and it'll only be called for pictures the user can see.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful comment @Andy. I'm not sure what templating is, is there a way I could learn about how to do what you're suggesting ?

Comment: Start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You might need to rephrase your question a bit and provide sample code to give context to get a better answer. For reference, see the docs page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1

An `ObservableCollection` is essentially a collection that fires notifications for various operations on the collection (e.g. an item is added or removed). Since you've tagged this as WPF, additionally this remark from the docs might be a good summary:

> WPF provides the `ObservableCollection<T>` class, which is a built-in implementation of a data collection that implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

So to directly answer your question, there is no "user" necessarily required to "observe" the collection per se, it is just an object that notifies when something about it changes. Without more context unfortunately I can't be more specific than that.

*Edit: rewording and spelling*